# Reciting Torah by heart?

Tags: torah-reading

I know there is a tradition that you must read Torah on the bimah from a scroll, and not recite the verses by heart.  What is the source of that tradition?  And is the reason only that you are less likely to make a mistake when reading than when reciting by heart, or are there others?  What about someone who can't read (blind or illiterate) but knows the text by heart?

(I asked about prayers in the siddur [before](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99134/is-it-ok-to-recite-prayers-by-heart).)

Comment: It's the same rule that forbids writing the oral torah

Comment: What is that rule?

Comment: Gittin 60b regarding that rule?

Comment: https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Yoma/Reading%20the%20Torah%20by%20Heart

Answer (score 2):

See:
[Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim
49](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.49.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
אע"ג דקיימא לן דברים שבכתב אי אתה רשאי לאומרם על פה כל דבר שרגיל ושגור בפי הכל כגון ק"ש וברכת כהנים ופרשת התמיד וכיוצא בהן מותר:

Even though we have established that things [from the Torah] which were written, you have no permission to recite them by heart, any thing that is routine and fluent in everyone's mouth, ofr example, the recitation of the Sh'ma and the Priestly Blessing and the section of the daily offering, and similar things to them is permitted.

This is based as the other commenter said on a Gemara in Gittin.
The [Aruch hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.49.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes more or less answering your question and giving reasons to be lenient.